# Raspberry PI cross compilation linking error - unknown symbol _dl_hwcap

Tags: raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, dynamic-linking

I have successfully set up a cross-complation environment for my RPI under 64 Bit ubuntu. I can compile and run a personal project using gstreamer just fine.

Due to performance-issues with gstreamer, I want to work on a fork of omxplayer. I adapted it to my environment, and compilation of ffmpeg and omxplayer themselves work just fine.

However, linking an actual executable (ffmpeg, or omxplayer.bin) yields a linking error I have been unable to resolve.

You find the full output of the last failing linking-step with verbose flags here:

https://gist.github.com/deets/3bba7c94017405d28f81

The error message is

```
ffmpeg_compiled/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so: undefined reference to `_dl_hwcap'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The missing symbol to me suggests something with dynamic loading. Maybe the libc or libdl are botched? But how come these are working just fine if compiling another project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the culprit. When setting up the crosscompilation-environment, make sure your copy of the RPI's libraries are correct. I had unresolved symbolic library links that needed fixing in my rsync'ed copy of the RPI's file-system.

Comment: Which symbolic links? I am having this exact same error (with omxplayer too by coincidence - or not). What command do you use to rsync correctly? I am using rsync -rl --delete-after --safe-links \
    --exclude='usr/share/***' \
    --exclude='usr/bin/***' \
    --exclude='usr/games/***' \
    --exclude='usr/sbin/***' \
    --exclude='usr/src/***' \
    pi@$1:/{lib,usr} .

Comment: The VM I did this on is long gone... I didn't investigate into rsync, so I can't comment on your command there. The libraries were mostly system-stuff under /lib/arm... if I remember correctly. But ultimately, just search for all links in your clone, and if they have an existing destination.

Comment: Thanks. I found another article with more info and found some broken links, but still couldn't get it to work. I'm going to try without the --safe-links option (even though it says to use it on several of the guides to RPi cross-compilation) and then search for broken links.